# Question about web forms, JavaScript validation function unreachable

Tags: javascript

Good day,

I've been working on this for class. I submitted the assignment and got a good grade - the professor didn't even lower my grade because I wasn't able to get this working, but I'm still frustrated because what I want this to do is to take a look at the Help Request form, alert me that it's checked, and to validate the email address. But the function seems to be unreachable.

I've made this fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/b7j3ekts/

Stack overflow requires that I post code as well, but the fiddle is better I think:

```
/* This function never fired. I spent alot of time with it and I'm really frustrated and even though I posted my problem online and am going back and forth with
   it, I kinda ran out of time to fix it. I was trying to do the part of the assignment where we looked to see if email was checked and then validated the email address. */

if (document.getElementById("contactemailH").checked === true) {

    alert("Checked!");

    /* Checks the email field to make sure that it's an email address in formHELP */

    var emailaddy2 = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

    if (document.forms["formHELP"]["FromAddress"].value.match(emailaddy2)) {
    }

    else {
        alert("Please input a valid email address.");
        return false;
    }

}
```

}

The offending code starts at around line 123 of the js file.

Any advice appreciated. :)

-- Mark

Comment: FromAddressH should be the tag right.

Comment: Also the first if only checks one of the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 if (document.getElementById("contactphoneH").checked === true ||document.getElementById("contactemailH").checked === true ) {

    alert("Checked!");

    /* Checks the email field to make sure that it's an email address in formHELP */

    var emailaddy2 = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\ 
 [[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z] 
 {2,}))$/;

    if (document.forms["formHELP"]["FromAddressH"].value.match(emailaddy2)) {
    }

    else {
        alert("Please input a valid email address.");
        return false;
    }

}
```

You just had misspelled tags.

Comment: Thank you so much arundeep, I really appreciate that. It was driving me batty. : )

Answer (score 0):

You seem to need an event listener. The JavaScript loads once, does anything you've marked as immediate, and then it just sits there dormant. If you want a function to run you have to call it by name, or tell JavaScript to watch for an event.

In your case I'd tell JavaScript to wait for the event "blur", which is when an element *was* focused and then loses focus, so it's great for form fields.

```
document.getElementById('contactemailH').addEventListener('blur', function(event) {
  validateEmail(event.target.value)
})
let validateEmail = function (emailaddy) {
  // do your check here
}
```

Let me know if I'm off-base; I'm reading your fiddle on a mobile and jsfiddle is **not** mobile friendly *at all*.